# MySQL update +- amount

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, crud

I got this update thing i cant figure out. The save button seems to be working, its updating the table. I cant seem to figure out the SaveToStock method. It throws me this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ''90' at line 1

I tried putting a breakpoint, got this. [Break data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GICtX.jpg)

### Save button

```
protected void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();

        MySQLParser parser = new MySQLParser(connection);

        int nonsoldamount = 0;
        if (parser.hasRows("SELECT * FROM dpf_stock WHERE geometry = '" + DropDownListGeometry.SelectedValue + "' AND length = '" + DropDownListLength.SelectedValue.Replace(',', '.') + "' AND CPSI = '" + DropDownListCPSI.SelectedValue + "'"))
        {
            nonsoldamount = Convert.ToInt32(parser.readSelectCommand("SELECT amount FROM dpf_stock WHERE geometry = '" + DropDownListGeometry.SelectedValue + "' AND length = '" + DropDownListLength.SelectedValue.Replace(',', '.') + "' AND CPSI = '" + DropDownListCPSI.SelectedValue + "'", "amount"));
            if (editing)
            {
                oldamount = Convert.ToInt32(parser.readSelectCommand("SELECT amount FROM dpf_sale where dpfSaleID = " + IDdpfSale, "amount"));
                nonsoldamount = nonsoldamount + oldamount;
            }
            if (nonsoldamount < Convert.ToInt32(TextBoxAmount.Text))
            {
                ErrorMessage.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<span class=\"error\">There are only " + nonsoldamount + " in stock with the selected attributes</span>"));
                return;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ErrorMessage.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<span class=\"error\">There are 0 in stock with the selected attributes</span>"));
            return;
        }

        string sql_query = "";

        if (editing)
        {
            oldamount = Convert.ToInt32(parser.readSelectCommand("SELECT amount FROM dpf_sale where dpfSaleID = " + IDdpfSale, "amount"));

            sql_query = "UPDATE dpf_sale SET orderNo = ?orderNo, fk_operatorID = ?operator, status = ?status, amount = ?amount, geometry = ?geometry, length = ?length, CPSI = ?CPSI " +
                        "WHERE dpfSaleID = ?IDdpfSale";
        }
        else
        {
            sql_query = "INSERT INTO dpf_sale (orderNo, fk_operatorID, amount, geometry, length, CPSI, status) " +
                        "VALUES (?orderNo, ?operator, ?amount, ?geometry, ?length, ?CPSI, ?status)";
        }

        MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand(sql_query, connection);

        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?IDdpfSale", IDdpfSale);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?orderNo", TextBoxOrderNo.Text);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?operator", DropDownListOperator.SelectedValue);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?geometry", DropDownListGeometry.SelectedValue);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?length", DropDownListLength.SelectedValue.Replace(',', '.'));
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?status", DropDownListStatus.SelectedValue);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?CPSI", DropDownListCPSI.SelectedValue);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?amount", TextBoxAmount.Text);

        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        saveToStock();
    }

    editing = false;
    IDdpfSale = 0;
    Response.Redirect("dpf_sale.aspx");
}
```

### Stock Change

```
private void saveToStock()
{
    connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
    parser = new MySQLParser(connection);
    connection.Open();

    string sql_stock = "";
    string sql_log = "";
    int newsaleID;

    if (editing == true)
    {
        sql_stock = "UPDATE dpf_stock SET amount = amount + " + oldamount + " - " + TextBoxAmount.Text + " WHERE geometry = '" + DropDownListGeometry.SelectedValue + "' AND length = '" + DropDownListLength.SelectedValue.Replace(',', '.') + "' AND CPSI = '" + DropDownListCPSI.SelectedValue;
        sql_log = "UPDATE dpf_stock_log SET amount = " + TextBoxAmount.Text + " WHERE sale = 1 and id = " + IDdpfSale;
    }
    else
    {
        newsaleID = Convert.ToInt32(parser.readSelectCommand("SELECT MAX(dpfSaleID) id FROM dpf_sale", "id"));
        sql_log = "INSERT INTO dpf_stock_log (id, assembly, sale, amount) VALUES (" + newsaleID + ", 0, 1, " + TextBoxAmount.Text + ")";

        if (parser.hasRows("SELECT * FROM dpf_stock WHERE geometry = '" + DropDownListGeometry.SelectedValue + "' AND length = '" + DropDownListLength.SelectedValue.Replace(',', '.') + "' AND CPSI = '" + DropDownListCPSI.SelectedValue + "'"))
        {
            sql_stock = "UPDATE dpf_stock SET amount = amount - " + TextBoxAmount.Text + " WHERE geometry = '" + DropDownListGeometry.SelectedValue + "' AND length = '" + DropDownListLength.SelectedValue.Replace(',', '.') + "' AND CPSI = '" + DropDownListCPSI.SelectedValue;
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
    }

    MySqlCommand myCommand1 = new MySqlCommand(sql_stock, connection);
    myCommand1.ExecuteNonQuery();



    MySqlCommand myCommand2 = new MySqlCommand(sql_log, connection);
    myCommand2.ExecuteNonQuery();
    connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: By the look of the screenshot you've missed the closing `'` at the end - https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNhMw.png

Comment: Which is **the least worst thing** that can happen when you use string concatenation to make SQL queries. Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection, please use parameterised queries.

Comment: @stuartd This site is only gonna be used by a few people local. I added the ' same outcome. Thank you.